# Double stroke color of circle in svg

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

this is how i made circle with only stroke and no fill

```
fill: none !important;
stroke-width: 1px;
```

- I want double stroke.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sadly, you can't set an SVG to have a double stroke, only a dashed or solid stroke.

Instead, just create an element exactly the same but reduce the size/radius of it by however much you require.

```css
.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="1" />
  <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="38" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested in doing this with squares/rectangles as well as without multiple `<rect>` or `<circle>` entries, you can use the `outline` property to achieve the double line border in SVG and the `border-radius` property to make it work with circles.

```css
.double {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  outline: 4px double black;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="200">
  <rect class="double" height="50" width="50" x='25' y='25' />
  <circle class="double circle" r="25" cx='150' cy='50' />
</svg>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I simply didn't understand it correctly.

Comment: works with circles with border-radius (tested on Chrome + Firefox)

Answer (score 4):

To add another more generic solution:

This can also be done with a filter by applying a [dilate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feMorphology) to expand the element by `radius=` in all directions, and then [composite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feComposite) `xor` the source and dilate together to leave just the difference between the two.

```html
<svg width="600">
  <filter id="dilate-and-xor">
    <feMorphology
      in="SourceGraphic"
      result="dilate-result"
      operator="dilate"
      radius="1"
    />
    <feComposite
      in="SourceGraphic"
      in2="dilate-result"
      result="xor-result"
      operator="xor"
    />
  </filter>

  <circle
    class="circle"
    cx="450"
    cy="50"
    r="40"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="5"
    fill="none"
    filter="url(#dilate-and-xor)"
  />

  <rect
    class="circle"
    x="250"
    y="20"
    width="50"
    height="50"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="5"
    fill="none"
    filter="url(#dilate-and-xor)"
  />
  
  <path 
    d="M 10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" 
    stroke="black" 
    fill="transparent"
    stroke-width="5"
    filter="url(#dilate-and-xor)"
  />
</svg>
```